# Accessing 2 different cloudkit accounts in one app

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I need to access 2 different cloudkit databases, and copy information from one to the other(including images). One of the databases is mine and the other one is a friend which I have access to. I cant seem to figure out how to access both in one app so I can download the information from one and upload it to the other one. I can do one at a time but that doesn't do me any good.

The following code works to get access to one of the containers, but how do I switch to a different account to get access to the other container?

```
var container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.lastname.firstname.MyAppName")
var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
var currentRecord: CKRecord?
var publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
```

Should I be doing this with a phone app or should I create a mac app?

Thanks!

Comment: You say you have two databases. How were the databases created? By the same app or different apps? In the same container or different containers? In the public or private database?

Comment: Both are public, created with different apps, different containers. Example:  iCloud.com.myLastName.myFirstName.MyAppName - is one container iCloud.com.friendsLastName.friendsFirstName.someAppName - is the other container.

Answer (score 1):

An app is not allowed to access the CloudKit container of another app from another developer. That would be a terrible security problem if it were possible.

An app can access multiple containers only if both containers are from the same developer.

So the short answer to your question is that what you wish to do is impossible (thankfully).

Comment: I developed both apps(one on my account and the other one on my friends account) and have access to both containers. I have his login information and can get to the cloudkit database of both apps. The problem is that the old data is still valid on my account and is time consuming to get the data again and he wants the data converted to the new app which is on his account now. Is this because we both have a single user account and cannot add people to my team? If I could add him to my team would I then have access to both accounts?

Comment: Having the login for the accounts is irrelevant and has nothing to do with how your app has access to CloudKit containers. The containers must be associated with the same developer account used to build and sign the app.

Answer (score 1):

As the two apps are from different developer accounts they cannot access each others containers.

If you have access to both developer accounts, there are a few ways to migrate the data:

- update the old app to download the data to local storage (eg core data). Then copy the data file(s) to the new app and have it upload.
- use [CloudKit JS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkitjs) or [CloudKit Web Services](http://http:/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) on your Mac to copy the data.
- a single app could use CloudKit and CloudKit JS on different containers.

Comment: This sounds like something I should try. It might be nice to have a utility like this for this project as well as others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple in the WWDC 2016 announced shared database capabilities, see this video.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/

The details of shared cloudkit records are talked about around 20minutes into the video.In short you can share specific records with other named users. I haven't used the new facility yet, but it looks promising.

Your other option would be to use something like DropBox; creating public links to the images you want to share using their API.

https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/

Which is better; I don't know. Using both my current app, and when it comes to small chunks of data they are the same. But when it comes to dealing with larger chunks, assets in cloudKit speak. DropBox seems to have the edge as I write this [Dec 2016] at least it is faster, noticeably faster.